# OutOfMemory when read the Byte array has 1 GB data

Tags: apache-flex, out-of-memory

When I read the ByteArray to IDataInput it thows the Out Of Memory issue around 1 GB bytes are available in the IDataInput. So If I read the ByteArray it show the issue kindly see below of My Code data as a paramter that has 1 gb file

```
  ByteArray:buf = new ByteArray();
  data.readBytes(buf);
```

Look forward the reply as soona s possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: What else do you need to know? The file you're trying to read is just too big for the Flash VM to handle.

Comment: Actually in my flex application public function ZipFile(data:IDataInput) { ByteArray:buf = new ByteArray(); data.readBytes(buf); }So reading 1 GB file from the ByteArray it show an 1001 System is out of memory issue throws. is there any possible to extend virtural machine sapce? kindly help me

Comment: Why would you ever want to handle a single file of this size in Flash? Any content you can view, play or show in Flash can be broken down into smaller chunks.

Comment: Actually our requirement is to get the zip file and upload on our project. So for this we have 1 GB file of Zip. So while we upload the Out Of Memory issue coming we can only have single file to do

Comment: You don't have to read the file into memory to do a simple upload (unless you want to do modifications first). Flash 'streams' it to the server for you.

Comment: Below 1 GB File automatically upload as per the code I mentioned above but If the FileStream Size touch 1 GB it throws Out Of Memory error look forward ur help